# Showing the closure of the set of finite sequences is the set of sequences which have limit $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I am trying to show for $c_{00} \subset l_\infty$ we have that $[c_{00}] = c_0$ where $c_{00}$ represents the set of finite sequences i.e. $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N,0,\dots)$ and $c_0$ is the set of sequences which have limit $0$.

I have shown that, for any accumulation point $x \in l_\infty$ of $c_{00}$ we have that $x \in c_0$ i.e. I have shown that $[c_{00}] \subset c_0$ but I am having troubles showing the opposite inclusion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x \in c_0$, define a sequence $(x^n)^\infty_{n=1}$ in $c_{00}$ by 
$$
x^n_i = x_i \text{ for } i \le n\ \ \ and \ \ \ x^n_i = 0 \text{ for } i > n.
$$

Then $\|x - x^n\|_\infty = \sup_{i > n} |x_i| \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=(x_1,x_2,...)\in c_{0}$ (that is, $\lim x_n=0$). For each $n\ge 1$, let us define $X_n=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,0,0,0,...)$.

Now, since $\lim x_n=0$, given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N>0$ such that for each $n\ge N$ we have $|x_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Therefore, $\sup_{n\ge N}|x_n|\le\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$...$(*)$

Then, for $n\ge N$ we have:
$\begin{eqnarray}
\|X_n-X\|&=&\|(0,0,...,0,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},...)\|\\
&=&\sup_{k\ge 1}|x_{n+k}|\\
&\le&\sup_{n\ge N}|x_n|\\
&<&\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}$

Then, by definition of norm convergence, $X_n\to X$. Therefore $X\in[c_{00}]$.